# Kivy Screen only loading the first time and gives error when changing screen with sm.switch_to()

Tags: python, kivy

I hope this isn't a stupid question.

I'm building a Kivy app

I have 4 screens, a welcome, scanner, input, and results

My screens load all perfectly the first time around, now once I try going back to the first screen I get an error that says that my screen (welcome, scanner) doesn't exist when I try to switch screens from my main.py using the switch_to().

This my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class WelcomeScreen(Screen):
    def display_scanner(self):
        sm = self.manager
        sm.switch_to(sm.get_screen('scanner')) # here the `scanner` screen is loaded

class ScannerScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScannerScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print('ScannerScreen initialized')


    def scan_barcode(self):

                 try:
                    # some logic and then
                
                    sm = self.manager
                    sm.switch_to(sm.get_screen('result'))

                except:
             
                    sm = self.manager
                    sm.switch_to(sm.get_screen('input'))
      

class InputScreen(Screen):
    
    def update_database(self):

        # update the database
     
        sm = self.manager
        sm.switch_to(sm.get_screen('scanner'))


class ResultScreen(Screen):
    def display_scanner(self):
        sm = self.manager
        
        # Check if the ScannerScreen has already been added
        scanner_screen = sm.get_screen('scanner')

        if not scanner_screen:

            # If it hasn't been added yet, add it now

            scanner_screen = ScannerScreen(name='scanner') # I added this just to try to make sure my 'scanner' class is instantiated

            sm.add_widget(scanner_screen) 


        for s in sm.screens: # here is where I see there is a problem only `input` and `result` are outputted
            print(s.name)

        # Switch to the ScannerScreen
        sm.current = 'scanner'
  

class BrainlyBinApp(App):
    def build(self):
        screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        print("Adding screens to screen manager...")
        screen_manager.add_widget(WelcomeScreen(name='welcome'))
        print("WelcomeScreen added")
        screen_manager.add_widget(ScannerScreen(name='scanner'))
        print("ScannerScreen added")
        screen_manager.add_widget(InputScreen(name='input'))
        print("InputScreen added")
        screen_manager.add_widget(ResultScreen(name='result'))
        print("ResultScreen added")
        print(screen_manager.screen_names) # here I can see all 4 screens are added to the manager
        return screen_manager


if __name__ == '__main__':
    BrainlyBinApp().run()
```

This is my .kv file:

```
<WelcomeScreen>:
        
        Button:
            on_press: root.display_scanner()

<ScannerScreen>:

        Button:
            on_press: root.scan_barcode()


<InputScreen>:
           
        Button:
            on_press: root.update_database()


<ResultScreen>:

        Button:
            on_press: root.display_scanner() # this should bring the user back to the scanner screen
```

It loads the first time after the `welcome` screen so I know it's not a typo
I'm still very new to programming and I would appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: You can try to avoid switch_to(), you should use the current property of the ScreenManager

Comment: I tried using that on the `ResultScreen` in the .kv file, but that's where I saw that there was an issue

Comment: I did some troubleshooting and I've realized that the screens switch between each other, if I only use `root.manager.current`

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Saxtheowl, the switch_to() was really what was causing the issue, I was able to implement the same thing using just the sm.current, and now its working

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was removing the switch_to() and implementing the sm.current = 'scanner`

```
class WelcomeScreen(Screen):
    def display_scanner(self):
        sm = self.manager
        sm.current = 'scanner'
```